# Unable to start dunst notification daemon for user

Tags: linux, arch-linux, notifications, dbus, dunst

I did a clean arch install with only XDM and i3 to serve as login/window managers. I have also installed dunst package; and according to [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dunst) nothing else is required for it to work.

However, when trying to send notifications, I receive:

```
Unable to send notification: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached
```

The troubleshoot section on same wiki page suggests assignment of `DISPLAY` variable. I have the following in my `.xinitrc`:

```
source /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh
```

which does exactly this:

```
➜ cat /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh     
#!/bin/sh

systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

if command -v dbus-update-activation-environment >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        dbus-update-activation-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
fi
```

Checking at [dunst's FAQ](https://dunst-project.org/faq/), it mentions availability of `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable. And to check the `gdbus` command for running notification daemons:

```
➜ gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.DBus --object-path /org/freedesktop/Dbus --method org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
(['org.freedesktop.DBus', ':1.40', 'org.freedesktop.systemd1', 'org.a11y.Bus', ':1.20', ':1.21', 'net.tenshu.Terminator20x1a6021154d881c', ':1.0', ':1.1', 'org.PulseAudio1', 'org.pulseaudio.Server', ':1.2', ':1.16', ':1.17', ':1.18', ':1.19'],)

➜ echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS 
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus

➜ echo $DISPLAY 
:0
```

I do have the dunst service listed in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services` directory.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  64 Oct 23 03:43 ca.desrt.dconf.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 107 Sep  6 00:40 org.a11y.Bus.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68 Feb 20 10:29 org.dharkael.Flameshot.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116 Aug  1  2018 org.freedesktop.ColorHelper.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  51 Feb 20 18:37 org.freedesktop.systemd1.service -> ../system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60 Oct 27 22:09 org.gnome.GConf.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111 Sep  5 05:36 org.gtk.GLib.PACRunner.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100 Jan  2 17:13 org.knopwob.dunst.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56 Nov 22  2017 org.xfce.calendar.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 115 Jan 28 05:22 org.xfce.FileManager.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56 Nov 22  2017 org.xfce.orage.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124 Jan 28 05:22 org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110 Jan 28 05:22 org.xfce.Thunar.service
```

According to [this blog post](https://linuxconfig.org/get-better-notifications-in-your-wm-with-dunst#h8-switch-the-dbus-service); I should switch to dunst as my notification service. But I have no idea which notification service is my current one!

I do have 2 separate `dbus.service` listed as running in my `systemctl status` list; one in the `system.slice` tree and another in `user@1000.service` tree.

Any pointers as to how should I configure my dbus daemon would be helpful,

Comment: I have a file at `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` which has:

```[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/bin/dunst
```

The `Exec` command originally had `notify-osd` for me. After making the change, I had to kill the `notify-osd` process and then run `systemctl --user start dunst.service`.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. @IndradhanushGupta Do you use any other display/login managers?

Comment: I'm using `i3`. Maybe try adding a service file for the `org.freedesktop.Notifications` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with dunst after installing plasma. Plasma had registered it's own dbus service which was conflicting, causing `notify-send`, `slack`,... to hang when notifications were sent.

You can check whether this applies to you:

```
grep -ri freedesktop.Notifications /usr/share/dbus-1/services/
```

If you have multiple services registered, pick one and remove the others (preferably through a package manager, not `rm`)